# Update attributedString in UITextVIew without changing origin attributedString

Tags: uitextview, nsattributedstring, nslayoutmanager, nstextstorage, nstextcontainer

I am working to using UITextView to show RTF context,like an article, we usually see on webpage, in html style.  including `HEADING`,`PARAGRAPH`, `LIST` or `IMAGE`, `CODE_BLOCK` `BOLD` etc.

the data format I get from api is like below

```
struct TextModel
{
   let text: String = "heading list item 1 item 2 paragraph, bold "
   let attributes: [Attribute]
}

struct Attribute 
{
   let type: Type = LIST
   let range Range = (start: 0, length: 10) 
}

enum Type 
{
  case LIST
  case LINK
  case BOLD
  case PARAGRAPH
   ....
}
```

so for the "heading list item 1 item 2 paragraph" I want to showing something like below

```
heading

list
  1. item 1 
  2. item 2
paragraph bold
```

but with no inserting extra `\r` or `1 2 number`
it will be show on textView like this

```
heading list item 1 item 2 paragraph bold
```

api 's text doesn't have \r or number, the logic api provide is if they pass to iOS a `LIST` or `PARAGRAPH` it will be a "block" text, so it should support line change automatically, also pass a `LIST` then iOS should add the `1,2,3...` number at the beginning.

so basically I can set different attribute key value based on the `Type` the data returns
but as you can see the above data has no `\r` or `\n` to do the linebreak,
and the `LIST Type` doesn't have the order number `1,2,3...` which need me to add into the NSAttributedString.

Originally I am planning to manually add these `\r` or `\n` or `1,2,3`
but after inserting those, it will change the range data which api returns at the beginning, then I can't figure out what's the correct range for each `TYPE`. and to compute the updated range is very complicated.

so my question is without change the source string of the NSAttributedString, can I change the text during the time when I render the text through attributedString on UITextView?

is there any way I can change in `NSTextStorage` or `NSLayoutManger` or `NSTextContainer`
basically mainly thing I need to add these linkbreak, `\r` or `\n` and
show ordered list with `1,2,3` prefix without change origin data?

couple thoughts I have:

1. is there a method I can put always put linebreak `\r` before certain index?
2. can I change the textStorage text when call layout manager generate glyph?